# Gameplan for Upgrading SQL Server fr 2014 to 2017 & 2022

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

First I would like to say sorry if my knowledge within the DBA realm is very limited since I and several other team members were just given this project because we are significantly resource-limited.

The task given was to upgrade several SQL Server instances from 2014 to 2017 and some to 2022 since it is looming EOS next year. The scope will also be combining several databases into one instance. We have come up with a plan on how to execute it, but we need some validation that this step is okay, and get some advice & suggestions for the deployment.

**Pre Upgrade**

1. Backups
   We would first backup all the databases which we will upgrade into the .bak format. We will also save snapshots in case the .bak fails.
2. Testing Said Backups
   After the backup completes, we will create a VM to restore the backups to ensure that the .bak or the snapshots are able to be used in case of an issue during the upgrade (this step is mandatory since the client is wary because previous snapshots have failed)
3. We will generate a Data Migration Assistant (DMA) report in order to figure out which SP and functions are not compatible after the upgrade.
4. This will all be done in a development stage first, if all succeed, then we will proceed in prod.

**Upgrade**

1. We will fix said SP & functions from the DMA report which will have issues after the upgrade
2. Create a downtime period which we will also coordinate with the operations team to stop all jobs to and from the databases (such as Talend and Microstrategy and so on).

**Post Upgrade**

1. Ensure that no SP and Functions are deprecated
2. Check data and accessibility
3. Check all the apps that are using the DB.
4. Document all changes made to SP and Functions

**Possible Alternative Method to be Used**

1. In the prod, make another instance and upgrade that one. If successful, then all apps will just re-route to the new instance and disable the old instance.

**Limitations**

1. Data in dev is significantly smaller, there is no resource to replicate
2. Creating a VM/server with the same spec as prod in order to test or to try and make it might be difficult because of the resource constraint

So this is the current game plan, is there any suggestion or advice? Is there anything we missed? Is there anything we should watch out for? Is there a better way to do it?

We are very limited in experience with dealing with this kind of task, hence we are really concerned about things going south. We will of course test this beforehand, even before upgrading the dev, to ensure everything is as smooth as can be.

Thank you very very much.

Comment: You might want to enable Query Store after upgrading. So e.g. you upgrade and leave comp. mode in SQL 2014, but you do enable Query Store. After 2 weeks you change the comp. mode to 2022 so you can find regressed queries in Query Store.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/change-the-database-compatibility-mode-and-use-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seconded Peter's suggestion about [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/change-the-database-compatibility-mode-and-use-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16). I'd even enable it now before the upgrade and save that data, from the current instances, when possible (on applicable instances running SQL Server 2016 or newer, if you have any).

The biggest issue you'll probably run into is performance regression with some queries. This is commonplace when upgrading and you guys are also changing your server setup / merging multiple databases into a single instance. And you're jumping multiple versions, especially the instances being upgraded to 2022 where there's been a magnitude of changes (even in 2019) since 2014. There's a lot happening at once, that some performance regression is inevitable.

And you won't be able to test with guarantee in your dev environments, especially since the data isn't the same. The quantity and statistical qualities of the data directly affect the query plans being generated.

Finally, I'd recommend that you upgrade all of the instances to the same version, of either 2019 or 2022 (2022 is still fairly new and potentially bug prone). For one, it'll be easier to manage all of them in regards to new features, when they're are all consistent in version. But also because 2017 already ended mainstream support and you don't want to be going through the upgrade process again in a few years, if you don't have to.

Sorry if this answer sounds like a downer, but it's the reality of how upgrades go.

Your best bet is to mimic the following as close as possible:

1. Enable Query Store on the current existing PROD instances, and let them collect data for a few months
2. Scale up a new server with the instance of the version of SQL Server that you plan to upgrade to.
3. Load the databases onto that instance that you'd eventually be consolidating there. Keep them up to date with the PROD data as best as possible. This can be achieved a number of ways such as with [Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver16), [Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16), or a number of other data synchronization methods.
4. Enable Query Store for all of these databases on the new server. Set their [Compatibility Levels](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2023/04/what-does-setting-the-sql-server-compatibility-level-do/) to match the server they came from. Let them collect data for a few months as well.
5. Review the data in the Query Store of each database on the old server compared to its correlating database on the new server. Also test the applications pointing to the new server routinely. Address any immediate performance regression problems.
6. Bump up the Compatibility Level of the databases on the new server to match that instance's version. Let them collect data for a few more months.
7. Compare the data between Query Stores again, and routinely test the apps pointing to the new server again, to determine any other performance regressions. Address accordingly.
8. Once comfortable with the performance and operation of the new server, cut over the applications to it. Keep the old server available but inaccessible by the applications (generally handled through networking changes) as a fallback in an emergency. (You may need a maintenance window to catch the new server up to the old server's data depending on what synchronization methodology you chose earlier.)
9. Monitor the Query Store and application performance on the new server for the next few months again, and if all good, retire the old server. Take appropriate backups and server snapshots as conducive to your recovery objectives.

I don't expect you'll be able to follow this perfectly, but as close as you can will get you closer to the ideal way to upgrade.

Comment: "Seconded Peter's suggestion about Query Store. I'd even enable it now before the upgrade and save that data, from the current instances."

I agree, but SQL Server 2014 does not have this feature yet ;-). For versions which do have it, I totaly agree!

Comment: @Peter heh good point. Hard to keep track of which features came in which versions now. I've been using SQL Server since 2008 R2 lol.

Comment: Thank you very much @Peter and j.d. I will definitely look into it more. Thank you for the help & knowledge :D Will try our best to do it right.

Comment: "Finally, I'd recommend that you upgrade all of the instances to the same version, of either 2019 or 2022 (2022 is still fairly new and potentially bug prone)" the reasoning behind this decision was the licenses available on the client. We have brought up the concerns about running a very recent version in prod, but they were adamant about the versions.. soo yea.. Thank you though!

Comment: @P5_ Best of luck! Btw, I know when you add up the "*couple months*" I mentioned in each step, you're almost at a year before cutover, which is a lot. It's mostly just to ensure you gather enough data to compare for any performance regressions. And particularly keeping in mind that some organization's workflows include queries that run only once a month or even only quarterly. It's a shame if a really important monthly query tanked and wasn't caught because not enough data was collected. But I understand you'll need to be realistic in your timeframe to implement too. So just food for thought.